# Best practice to redirect old static mobile website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, seo

I made an update of my non-responsive to responsive template and there is no need of my old fashion static mobile website and redirection to it (www.mysite.com/mobile/index.html). I want to completely remove directory with mobile site so that my old mobile site is not available anymore.

I'm concern with numerous 404 errors afterwords and their effect on my current Google search appearance. Maybe somebody could help me with advice what would be the best practice in this case.

I'm using CSM Joomla, Apache server and I have configured .htaccess file.

I would like the most to 301 redirect whole mobile directory to my home website link (www.mysite.com) but I'm aware that would be really bad from the Google's point of view. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting the whole site to the home page would be seen as a soft 404 by Google. Either redirect each page to the new equivalent, or return a 404/410 response.